# Place a div on the right side

Tags: html, css

I try to place a div on the right side of another one. I didn't succeed.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xn5uh/

I would like the main-content (colored in red) to be on the right side.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix spelling in overflow:auto;

```
.main-content
{            
    overflow:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `float` in your `.main-content` also. Write like this:

```
.main-content {
    background-color: Red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}
```

**OR**

Define `overflow:hidden` in your `.main-content`

```
.main-content {
        background-color: Red;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 600px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

In your example your `overflow` spelling is wrong

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Xn5uh/5/

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo on the maincontent class. [see the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn5uh/1/)

```
 overflow:auto; /*was ooverflow */
```

Answer (score 0):

for the `.main-Content` add `float:left`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn5uh/3/)